# Use input filename in Azure Biztalk Services expression

Tags: biztalk-services

I have a transform map which converts an xml message to another format. For a particular field from the output xml, I need to set its value according to the name of the input file.

Is there any way to access that information inside a logical expression or C# scripting functor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, we created an extra web api app just to do this processing... So we couldn't find a way to do this inside Wabs.